# objective c creating app ui from xml

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, user-interface

I am trying to parse xml (attached) and create a ui from it dynamically - with no success.
any ideas?

the XML looks like this:

```
<root>
 <view id="1" color="0.8 0.7 0.9 1.0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="480">
  <view id="2" color="0.9 0.1 0.3 1.0" x="20" y="20" width="280" height="200">
     <textfield id="5" x="10" y="90" width="180" height="40" placeholder="enter text" color="1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0" target_id="6"></textfield>
     <button id="4" color="0.2 0.2 0.2 1.0" x="220" y="90" width="40" height="40" title="push"></button>
  </view>
  <view id="3" color="0.1 0.8 0.3 1.0" x="20" y="240" width="280" height="100">
     <label id="6" color="0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0" x="20" y="20" title="some label..." width="200" height="80"></label>
  </view>
</view>
</root>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?   From your question, there is no way to know if you are asking "How do I parse XML?" to "How do I layout a bunch of views?" to "Why doesn't button id 4 work?"

Comment: Maybe he wants an answer to all your questions, that is a complete application! :-)

Comment: i've tried parsing the xml with NSXMLParser into a NSDictionary - but i'm not sure it's the best way because i dont know how to create the ui from the NSDictionary.

Comment: Oh, so my answer was a waste of time then. This is why you should put as much information as possible into your question: I could have spent that time actually helping you.

Comment: Re-ask your question.  Include the XML above *and* state clearly that you have an NSDictionary parsed out of it successfully.  Then show what you've tried in bringing up your UI.  If you don't know how to start doing that, state so.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm new here, i'll do my best being more specific in further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any more information, I'm going to assume you're asking for the best way to parse XML in Objective-C. And the answer to *that* question is to use the `NSXMLParser` class.

The class that you use the `NSXMLParser` in has to be flagged as being an `NSXMLParserDelegate`, so your .h file will look something like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyParsingController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate>

@end
```

Now, assuming you've got all of the XML you posted in your question in an `NSString` called `XMLString`, you can then turn the string into an `XMLData` object, initialize your `NSXMLParser`, and set it going by calling its `parse` method:

```
NSData * XMLData = [XMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:XMLData];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
[parser parse];
```

Once the parser is running, it'll call its delegate methods as it goes through your XML data, and you then need to interpret that data to construct a data model which you can then use to build your GUI. I'm not going to write that bit for you, but as an example of how to parse some XML, here's the code from one of my recent projects:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"device"]){
        self.currentDeviceID = [[SRDeviceID alloc]init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"deviceList"]){
        [self.pairingTableView reloadData];
    }


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"device"]){
        [self.deviceIDListFromServer addObject:self.currentDeviceID];
    }

    NSString* finalParsedString = [self.currentParseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"deviceName"]){
        self.currentDeviceID.deviceName = finalParsedString;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"UUID"]){
        self.currentDeviceID.uuid = finalParsedString;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"deviceLocation"]){
        self.currentDeviceID.location = finalParsedString;
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"deviceLastSeenTime"]){
        self.currentDeviceID.lastSeenTime = finalParsedString;
    }

    self.currentParseString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    [self.currentParseString appendString:string];
}
```

Hope that helps.